# Converting specific textFields into the integer -1

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I'm trying to create a Sudoku solver. So far I have created the interface using a 9x9 grid of textFields, where you enter the numbers into. I went to convert each textField into an integer for my 2d array, however the textfields left blank obviously won't convert to an integer, and cause an error.

Sample of my code:

```
    grid[1][1] = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
    grid[1][2] = Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText());
```

How can I make it so that all empty textFields can get converted into -1, while all filled in textFields

Comment: Use length of the text to detect if the string is empty or not

Comment: And store your text fields in a 2d array, so you can loop over them like the `grid` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the String is empty before applying it to the integer:

```
if(!textField_1.getText().equals("")){
    grid[1][1] = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
}else{
    grid[1][1] = -1;
}
```